# Google maps v3 API only loading after refresh / Authentication goes very slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google maps v3 API. When i visit the page with the map i sometimes get following error : `"custom.js:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"`.

API's enabled on the key:

- Google Maps Directions API
- Google Maps Distance Matrix API
- Google Maps Elevation API
- Google Maps Geocoding API
- Google Maps JavaScript API

When i reload the page, everything is working fine. This doesn't work 100% of the time. Multiple reloads are needed on some occasions.

I did notice that when the map isn't loading correctly this script is running in my head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fmayan-co.com%2Fen%2Foutlets&amp;MYKEY&amp;callback=_xdc_._h7cv8d&amp;token=60166"></script>
```

After 10-20 seconds this script goes away and when i refresh the page after this script goes away, my map is working correctly.

Things i tried without results:

- Putting the script to load the API in the footer.
- Not using async or defer.
- Adding specific url's to my api key.
- Not using a api key

Loading the api script in the Head of my page:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" async defer></script>
```

My script to render the map and place markers on the map (loaded in the footer)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#animation').addClass('animate');

    $('.heart img').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        container: '#animation',
        content: function () {
            return $(this).attr('alt');
        }
    });

    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.heart img').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.heart img').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            } else {
                $(this).popover('toggle');
            }
        });
    });

    function render_map($el) {

        var $markers = $(document).find('#locations .data-source li');

        var args = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
            }
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);

        map.markers = [];

        index = 0;
        $markers.each(function() {
            add_marker($(this), map, index);
            index++;
        });

        center_map(map);
    }

    function add_marker($marker, map, index) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));
        var image = '../../img/maps-leaf.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        map.markers.push(marker);
        if ($marker.html()) {
            $('#locations .data-display').append('<li class="linkage" id="p'+index+'">'+$marker.html()+'</li>');

            $(document).on('click', '#p' + index, function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                setTimeout(function() { infowindow.close(); }, 5000);
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: $marker.html(),
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open( map, marker );
            });
        }
    }

    function center_map(map) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
            bounds.extend( latlng );
        });

        if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {
            map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
            map.setZoom( 16 );
        } else {
            map.fitBounds( bounds );
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#map').each(function(){
            render_map( $(this) );
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe looks like you try to instantiate the map before the Google Maps API JavaScript is loaded (you're using `async` attribute there). That's why it sometimes throws `google is not defined` error.

In other words, `document.ready` is called before `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY` is loaded.

Google Maps API allows you to use `callback` parameter in the URL with a name of a function that's called after the API is fully loaded. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.

So in your case you'll use URL like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap
```

And then initialize the map:

```
initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. where should i place initMap() ? Should ik go inside the render_map() function or should it be first on the page? and remove the new google.maps inside render_map ?

Comment: Callback function has to be in the top level scope (`window` scope). So for example `window.initMap = function() {...}` or you could just leave `render_map` where it is and change it to `window.render_map = function() {...}`.

Comment: so when i do window.render_map = function() my callback needs to be render_map() right? Sorry , my javascript knowledge is not very good

Comment: Yes, just `render_map` without parenthesis. You could ideally also put `window.render_map` outside `document.ready` event but I'm not sure whether it's not dependent on any scope variables.

Comment: ok, so my javascript is this: `window.render_map = function($el) {..}` and my callback = render_map. But in my console i get : `render_map is not a function`